# Calling a method multiple times with a Scanner object in it

Tags: java

I have a method in my program that reads in a word from a text file. I need to call this method every time the game restarts but it contains my scanner object. I am not sure if it is right to call this method multiple times with this in it as I would be creating the same instance over and over?

I have tried to move the scanner object into my constructor but because it uses a FileReader it needs to be enclosed in a try/catch block so I would need to include the rest of the code that reads the word in, and I don't think this should go in the constructor. I might be really off the mark here but I'm just a bit confused on where the best place is to put these new objects.

As you can see in my `readWord()` method I have included the scanner object to show you where it oroginally was and also in the constructor to demonstrate my question properly.

Also is it bad practice to declare scanner/filereader as global variables and then initialise them like I have done? Or should I be declaring them in the method like I have done in `readWord()`?

```
public class Hangman {

private ArrayList<String> wordArray;
private FileReader fr;
private Scanner wordIn;

public Hangman() {
    wordArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    fr = new FileReader("words.txt"); // Needs to be in try/catch
    wordIn = new Scanner(fr); // Not sure this should go here?

}

public void readWord() {
    try {

        Scanner wordIn = new Scanner(new FileReader("words.txt")); // This is where scanner originally was, not sure this goes here if calling method multiple times?

        while (wordIn.hasNextLine()) {
            wordArray.add(wordIn.nextLine().toUpperCase());
        }

        Collections.shuffle(wordArray);
        word = wordArray.get(0);

        System.out.println("Word: " + word);

        scan.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: File not found.");
    }

}
```

Comment: remove that Scanner wordIn line there. you've already done all that in your constructor

Comment: @Stultuske I know it is there twice, I am not sure where this line needs to go so I left both there to demonstrate my question.

Comment: remove it from your readWord method.
if you do want to run that method multiple times from the same instance, remove it from the constructor, and change the line in your method to: wordIn = new Scanner(new FileReader("words.txt"));

Comment: I do need to call this method multiple times. If I initialise the scanner in `readWord()` wouldn't I be creating the same instance over and over again every time that method is called? If that is the case, is that a bad thing? @Stultuske

Comment: Keep `readWord` mostly as is, but remove the code that shuffles the word list.  Now you can call `readWord` once in the constructor and never need to call it again.  Put the list-shuffling code with your  start-a-game code instead.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Thank you, Kevin! That sounds like a better idea.

Comment: First, `scan.close();` is incorrect, it should be `wordIn.close()`, also it should be in a `finally` clause or the `Scanner` need to be declare in a `try-with-resource` to prevent some problems. See about `AutoCloseable`. Note that `wordIn` inside `readWord` is the local variable, not the instance member. So the instance member is NEVER closed

Comment: And definitely **do not** make that `Scanner`, the one you use to read the word list, global!  It's completely useless to any other code once you've read the word list and closed it, and so should never be seen except within `readWord`.